# Git: Convention over Configuration principle?

Tags: git, gitlab, github-for-windows, github-for-mac

I know the basic Git but here I have an existing branch as remotes/origin/aditya. How do I switch to that?

```
 git branch -a

* (HEAD detached at origin/aditya1)
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/aditya-design
remotes/origin/aditya1
remotes/origin/aditya2
```

I know normally we do `git checkout branch-name`
but here I am unable to change and set my branch to

```
remotes/origin/aditya1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried git checkout -t origin/aditya1 and it created a new local branch as aditya1 instead of switching to the existing remotes/origin/aditya2.
I thought Git takes care of the remotes and will handle the branch but it isn't.

Comment: Have you tried `git checkout aditya1`?

Comment: @NilsWerner Yes I have

Answer (score 1):

Remote branches are only references. If you checkout you will create a new local branch that starts were your HEAD was at that moment (in you case the detached origin/aditya1.

You probably want to do something similar to

```
git checkout -b aditya1 -t origin/aditya1
```

And than work on this newly created local branch.